# Creatign a Pie Chart In Matplotlib Using List Comprehensions

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently doing a Python project where I'm building a pie chart that shows the current carbon intensity outputs for different fuel types in England using this API. I've been able to extract the data I need and now just need to place it into a pie chart using matplotlib. Here is the code I have so far.

```
import requests
import pprint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


filename = ("https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/regional/england")
r = requests.get(filename)
print("Status Code:", r.status_code)

#Store API responce in a variable
responce_dict = r.json()

# get data
datas = responce_dict["data"][0]["data"][0]["generationmix"]


# print data
pprint.pprint(datas)

for data in datas:
    print(data["perc"])

for data in datas:
    print(data["fuel"])

y = np.array([x for x in data["perc"]])
mylabels = ([x for x in data["fuel"]])
plt.pie("y", labels = mylabels)
plt.show()
```

As you can see I'm using list comprehensions to get the "perc" data for the carbon intensity for each fuel type that the pie chart is based off on and the "fuel" data to get the labels for each fuel type. When I run this code I get the error of "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable". I'm not sure what is wrong with my code though I assume it would be an error within one of my list comprehensions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the lines

```
y = np.array([x for x in data["perc"]])
mylabels = ([x for x in data["fuel"]])
plt.pie("y", labels = mylabels)
```

with:

```
y = np.array([x['perc'] for x in datas])
mylabels = ([x['fuel'] for x in datas])
plt.pie(y, labels = mylabels)
```

Comment: The explanation to why this code works is this: Your code was trying to loop through an iterable returned from accessing the key "perc" in the data dictionary. But because the data was stored as a list of dictionaries (not a dictionary with values as lists), you needed to access the value for each dictionary in the list.